# How to work with android xml in graphical layout using eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have an iMac with 4GB of RAM and dual core cpu but when I try to work with android xml putting text, images, button, and playing with alignments in Relative layout it work so slow and finally if I work for some time eclipse is crashing with an error mentioning Java heap not enough space.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the maximum heap size avaliable for eclipse but it will work for a few minutes maybe an hour then you will get the same error message. to do so please follow these instructions:

1. Go to eclipse lanucer icon and right click and choose
2. Open Content->MacOS->eclipse.ini
3. Increase the memory to a suitable value.

please referee to eclipse on how to increase heap memory in the following link:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

it will show you a sample ini file to follow.

Stil eclipse suffers the memory leakage but this is just a work around.